# how java constructor does work?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I have the following program :

```
class A{
    int b = 50;
}

class B extends A{
    int b = 20;
}

public class Maini{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.b);
    }
}
```

and the result is 50 and I would like to know why?
before I run the code I am pretty sure that the result should be 20.

Comment: You're not using a constructor here. Add one in `B` and assign the value 20 to `b` in it.

Comment: `A::b` and `B::b` are different fields. You are printing `A::b` because your object variable `a` is of type `A`.

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with how constructors work.

Note that the member variable `b` in class `B` does not override the member variable `b` in class `A`. Only non-static, non-private methods can be overridden. Member variables cannot be overridden.

If you have an instance of class `B`, then it actually has two member variables called `b`: one in the superclass (`A`) part of the object, and one in the subclass part (`B`).

The reason that you see the value 50, which is the value of `b` in the `A` part of the object, is because the variable `a` in the `main` method is of type `A`. If you change this to `B`, you'll get 20:

```
B a = new B();  // instead of A a = ...;
```

Comment: your right! I choose the wrong topic!tnx btw!

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
A a = new B();
```

You are calling Bs constructor in an object of type A

In your program, you have given no constructor to B, so it looks to A.

In A, the value of int b is 50 and an object is of type A, hence the value is chosen as 50

If you had a constructor in B e.g.

```
B() { b = 20;}
```

the value would be 20.

Comment: Won't work, check this->https://ideone.com/oewyph

Answer (score 0):

When you write `A a = new B()` the object `a` is type `A`. This is why you're getting `b = 50`. If you want to get `b = 20`, you need to declare `a` as a `B` class

Hope it's clear enough.

Best

Comment: Constructor won't help, check this->https://ideone.com/oewyph

Comment: Yep my bad, srry ^^

Answer (score 0):

You think that you are creating a B but you have not written any constrcutors for the class B so  it looks to the super() constructor which is it's parents (A). So you now have an object of A. If you are curious about why A's object isi being created while there is no constructor to it too. A calls to it's super constructor too which is Java's Object Class's constructor.

I hope that I could make this point clear.

Answer (score 0):

use a intellitrace enabled IDE for better experience of coding.
1st of all you'l hav a default constructor if you are not imposing on it. 
Secondly you are defining an object of type 'A' not 'B'. if you want the output as 20 then you hav to include this B() {int b = 20;}.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this code Sniplet there is no constructor in Any class.
So JVM will create **no argument** default constructor in all classes.

While you are Running this then .

In the below code you
**a** is referring **class A** and having object of **class B**

```
A a = new B();
```

So here the Object **a** will have **class A** 's variable value.
and Class B object value as its calling Class B 's default constructor(`new B();`)
If  Class A and B have same Method like below Example:

```
class A{
    int b = 50;
    void method(){
        System.out.println("Method of A class");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    int b = 20;
    void method(){
        System.out.println("Method of B class");
    }
}

public class Maini{
    public static void main(String[] args){
     A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.b);
        a.method();
    }
}
```

Then `a.method()` will print 
 
**50 

Method of B class** 

as **a** is have **Class B** 's object.